# Changing and Variable after each Loop iteration.

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, foreach, listbox

I am currently working on a simple program that logs packages into an access database as they are picked up. Everything is working fine, but one thing.

If there are multiple packages in the listbox(lstPackages) it logs them all as having the same package ID(pid). The variable packageInfo contains the id, shop name, and run time. So it reads as "id shop run".

So I split packageInfo variable to create pid (just the package id), so I can get each packages unique ID.

I feel like since I am using a for each loop it should go as follows.

split, connect to database, query info, close connection, and repeat for each item in the listbox.

It does repeat for each item, but like I said, each record in the databse contains the same ID as the last item in the list box.

Thanks in advance!

```
For Each item In lstPackages.Items

            Dim idArray() As String = packageInfo.Split(" ")
            pid = idArray(0)


            con.ConnectionString = My.Settings.con
            cmd.Connection = con
            con.Open()
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO packages 
                  (ID, Shop, Run, [Time of Pickup], [PPU Name], [PPU ID], [tmSig])
                   VALUES ('" & pid & "', '" & shop & "', '" & run & "', '" & time & "', '" & ppu & "', '" & ppuid & "', ""C:\Users\Sam\OneDrive\Signatures\" & shop & "\" & runPath & "\" & shoptime & ".jpg"")"

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            con.Close()

        Next
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues with your code, namely the concatenation of strings to assemble an SQL command.  This is a security risk and you should be using the `Parameters` collection on the `Command` object.

Otherwise, you can simply rearrange your code to use the following structure.  I have left comments in the code where I think you have data and/or logic issues :-

```
con.ConnectionString = My.Settings.con
'Open the connection and hold it open
con.Open()

cmd.Connection = con
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

For Each item In lstPackages.Items

    '*** THIS IS THE PROBLEM 
    '"packageInfo" does not change for each iteration. Did you mean item.Split(" ")?
    Dim idArray() As String = packageInfo.Split(" ")
    pid = idArray(0)


    '*** WHERE ARE ALL OF THE VARIABLES FOR THIS SQL STATEMENT LOADED? ***
    '*** ARE THEY THE REMAINING ELEMENTS OF "idArray"?
    '*** THEY NEED TO BE INITIALISED SOMEWHERE

    'Use the same instantiated Command object to improve performance
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO packages 
              (ID, Shop, Run, [Time of Pickup], [PPU Name], [PPU ID], [tmSig])
               VALUES ('" & pid & "', '" & shop & "', '" & run & "', '" & time & "', '" & ppu & "', '" & ppuid & "', ""C:\Users\Sam\OneDrive\Signatures\" & shop & "\" & runPath & "\" & shoptime & ".jpg"")"

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

Next

con.Close()
```

See this Microsoft article for an example on using the `Parameter` collection. It is for an SQL UPDATE but the principle still works for SELECT.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2

Comment: The variables are initialized before the original for each statement, I just didn't post them to save room.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I did mean item split, it works perfectly. Also,  thank you for explaining where the security issues are!